# asp.net mvc authentication action doesn't get returnUrl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In a classical example of asp.net/mvc authentication LogOn action gets LogOnViewModel and returnUrl string to do an authentication and redirect to previous Url.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    if (!FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(model.UserName, model.Password))                                              
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect user name or password."); 

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
        return Redirect(returnUrl ?? "Bookings");
    }
    else
        return View();
}
```

But when request is handled by action returnUrl parameter is null, however there should be a value as author says. Could anybody please explain this?

Form from which I send request look like this: Views/Admin/LogOn.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <div id="login">
    <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Admin")) { %>
      <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
      <div><label>Username:</label><input name="userName" type="text" /></div>
      <div><label>Password:</label><input name="password" type="password" /></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Login" /></div>
    <% } %>
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

There is no hidden field generated on the form.

Authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/LogOn" timeout="2880">
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
      <user name="admin" password="hashedPassword"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: What does your submitting form look like? If you submit with a `POST` request, do you have a hidden element for the `returnUrl` parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you go to a page that isn't authenticated, the ReturnURL parameter is automatically added to your query string when you are redirected to the login page by the MVC framework.

Your current `<form>` tag in the view doesn't take this into account.  It always goes to the same action disregarding any existing QueryString values.

If you use:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
   // enter form html without the <form> tag
<% } %>
```

This will automatically create a `<form>` tag with 'action' value that takes into account any query strings that already exist on your page.

Comment: Action which user wants to invoke (www.mysite.com/Admin/Index) has [Authorize] attribute, that's why he is redirected to Logon page. Url on logon looks like www.mysite.com/Admin/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fAdmin%2findex /// using (Html.BeginForm()) didn't solve problem, still null in returnUrl

Comment: hmm, check that your variable is of the appropriate case:  ReturnUrl

Comment: Tried, didn't help. Request.QueryString is empty. It smells fishy, it should work. Routes for these requests  routes.MapRoute(
               "AdminMainPage",
               "admin/{action}",
               new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" }
           );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "AdminLogOn",
                "admin/logon/",
                new { controller = "Admin", action = "LogOn" }
            );                                                         Anyway thanks a lot for

Comment: Yeah, that was a bit of a long shot - can you update your question with the authentication settings in web.config and the new code in your view.

Comment: hmm... try using BeginForm without any parameters... it may be that it defaults all other query strings to null when you use that overload of the method.

Comment: Oh...!!! Omg!! you are right! BeginForm without parameters works. Many, many thanks bro!!

Comment: no prob - it was bugging me why it isn't working.   I guess the Html.BeginForm(string, string) method doesn't carry any QueryString forward, which I guess makes sense, since there's a Html.BeginForm(string, string, object) overload to specify the QueryString parameters.

Comment: Yeah, and there is no reason to add controller/action because it goes to the same controller and overloaded action with parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try including a hidden input element in your form:

```
<%:Html.Hidden("returnUrl", yourUrlHere) %>
```

Comment: I don't know from which page user was redirected to LogOn page. Is there any way to knew that?

Comment: See Comment by Remus it is automatically added. No need to add the hidden input element.